# XmlElement filter by attribute

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer

**Background:**
I have a simple XML sheet, which i cannot change, this is supplied by a 3rd party, The class and deserialization is maintained by us

**Question** How do i get the xml to deserialize properly, it obviously needs to somehow check the "name" attribute to decide which property to fill, but for the life of me i can not remember how to do this.
The current serializer we are using  is '**System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer**' and due to legacy, dependent code we can not change this.

**XML**

```
<result>
    <rowset name="divisions" key="accountKey" columns="accountKey,description">
      <row accountKey="1000" description="Division 1"/>
      <row accountKey="1001" description="Division 2"/>
      <row accountKey="1002" description="Division 3"/>
      <row accountKey="1003" description="Division 4"/>
      <row accountKey="1004" description="Division 5"/>
      <row accountKey="1005" description="Division 6"/>
      <row accountKey="1006" description="Division 7"/>
    </rowset>
    <rowset name="walletDivisions" key="accountKey" columns="accountKey,description">
      <row accountKey="1000" description="Wallet Division 1"/>
      <row accountKey="1001" description="Wallet Division 2"/>
      <row accountKey="1002" description="Wallet Division 3"/>
      <row accountKey="1003" description="Wallet Division 4"/>
      <row accountKey="1004" description="Wallet Division 5"/>
      <row accountKey="1005" description="Wallet Division 6"/>
      <row accountKey="1006" description="Wallet Division 7"/>
    </rowset>
</result>
```

**Class**

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("result", IsNullable = false)]
public class TestClass
{
    [XmlElement("rowset")]
    public EveXmlRowCollection<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("rowset")]
    public EveXmlRowCollection<Division> WalletDivisions { get; set; }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("row")]
    public class Division
    {
        [XmlAttribute("accountKey")]
        public int AccountKey { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
public class EveXmlRowCollection<T> : Collection<T>, IXmlSerializable 
{
    //... Other, Irrelevant implementations

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
        if (!reader.IsStartElement()) return;
        RowSetMeta.Name = reader.GetAttribute("name");
        RowSetMeta.Key = reader.GetAttribute("key");
        RowSetMeta.Columns = reader.GetAttribute("columns");
        reader.ReadToDescendant("row");
        while (reader.Name == "row") {
            if (reader.IsStartElement()) {
                var row = (T) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                Items.Add(row);
            }
            reader.ReadToNextSibling("row");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `EveXmlRowCollection`?

Comment: A very simple Custom Collection : 
public class EveXmlRowCollection<T> : Collection<T>, IXmlSerializable { ... }

Comment: not sure what you asked?

Answer (score 0):

What about doing it in two steps? First you can deserialize xml without any logic. Just create appropriate models:

```
[XmlRoot("result")]
public class Result
{
    [XmlElement("rowset")]
    public DivisionSet[] DivisionSets { get; set; }
}

public class DivisionSet
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("row")]
    public Division[] Divisions { get; set; }
}

public class Division
{
    [XmlAttribute("accountKey")]
    public int AccountKey { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Using them deserilizing is very trivial:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result));
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader("...XML..."))
{
    var result = (Result)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

And then you can create needed models using C# power:

```
public class DeserializedAndNormilizedObject
{
    public IEnumerable<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Division> WalletDivisions { get; set; }
}

var obj = new DeserializedAndNormilizedObject();
var devisionsSet = result.DivisionSets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "divisions");
if (devisionsSet != null)
{
    obj.Divisions = devisionsSet.Divisions;
}
// Same for walletDivisions
```

And you will return `DeserializedAndNormilizedObject` as a result of deserialization.

Comment: Downvoted, there needs to be a pure 'deserialization' method, a list in a list of values is terribly inefficient and poor code. Your method would work, yes, but it is not the answer I am looking for, thank you for the attempt however

Comment: Why it's "terribly inefficient"? It represents the structure of your XML.

Comment: Because I have to use 2 properties to expose the data (WalletDivisions  & Divisions) and due to technical requirements I am not allowed to use a 3rd, hidden property (or a list in list)

Comment: I updated the answer. My idea was that you will return object that you want. Of course you don't want to return an object with nested arrays. You just normalize deserialized object.